# Jmeter maven plugin | maven build not failing even if there are failures

Tags: maven, testing, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using JMeter maven plugin 2.6.0 I have a JMeter test plans which contains some test.

I am running the jmx plans through maven build. Even if there are failures, maven build is not getting failed.

I want the maven build to be failed. I am using false in jmeter maven plugin configuration.

The configuration my pom.xml is this:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <resultsFileFormat>jtl</resultsFileFormat>                       <resultsFileNameDateFormat>YYYY</resultsFileNameDateFormat>
                        <ignoreResultFailures>false</ignoreResultFailures>
                     </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Please add more information (like build logfiles).

Comment: summary +     28 in 00:00:09 =    3,3/s Avg:   539 Min:   187 Max:  1912 Err:     1 (3,57%) Active: 3 Started: 3 Finished: 0
[INFO] summary +     47 in 00:00:29 =    1,6/s Avg:  1416 Min:   183 Max: 30296 Err:     0 (0,00%) Active: 1 Started: 3 Finished: 2
[INFO] summary =     75 in 00:00:37 =    2,0/s Avg:  1089 Min:   183 Max: 30296 Err:     1 (1,33%)
[INFO] summary =     75 in 00:00:37 =    2,0/s Avg:  1089 Min:   183 Max: 30296 Err:     1 (1,33%)
[INFO] Tidying up ...    @ Thu Mar 01 11:14:30 UYT 2018 (1519913670499)
[INFO] ... end of run
[INFO] Completed Test: weaver_core_MISC.jmx

Comment: BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-01T11:15:17-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/511M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...

Comment: what's your value in pom.xml for `scanResultsForFailedRequests`? it should be true

Comment: I actually deleted it, because it did not work for me, but it was like this:
<scanResultsForFailedRequests> true </ scanResultsForFailedRequests>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this doc:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin
- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/e5ef94b6c300e23ac182c51b40dc7b293313e8ff/README.md#add-the-plugin-to-your-project

There is a bloc missing in your configuration:

```
<execution>
   <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
   <goals>
          <goal>results</goal>
   </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I added the changes and the final pom was like this:

Comment: <goal>results</goal> <ignoreResultFailures>false</ignoreResultFailures>              <scanResultsForFailedRequests>true</scanResultsForFailedRequests>
                            <scanResultsForSuccessfulRequests>true</scanResultsForSuccessfulRequests>
  <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results</resultsDirectory>                                                                          It worked for me

Comment: Not accept the vote, until I have 15 of reputation, sorry, greetings.